# Java 8 map signature: public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper)--why are there two Us?

Tags: java, generics, option-type

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper)
```

why are there two Us?

I understand the second U...The optional has a parameter describing the *kind* of Optional being returned.

But I don't get what the leading U is about. I'm struggling with call on the map method of optional with the following:

```
[javac]  return LocationAPIResponse.map(response -> Context.LocationContext.builder()...
[javac]                                            ^
[javac]  no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Optional<U> conforms to LocationContext
[javac]  where U,T are type-variables:
[javac]     U extends Object declared in method <U>map(Function<? super T,? extends U>)
[javac]     T extends Object declared in class Optional
```

I'm confused because the function I'm defining in map returns a LocationContext created by a builder. I'm confused by the two 'U's. Why is the compiler complaining

edit, fleshing out code sample to be more complete:

```
Optional<LocationServiceResponse> locationAPIResponse = locationServiceProxy.getLocation(locationServiceRequest);
    return locationAPIResponse.map(response -> Context.LocationContext
        .builder()
       .isNearby(response.getProximity().equals(ProxyEnum.NEARBY) ? 1 : 0)
       .lat(response.getLatitude().orElse(0))
       .lng(response.getLongitude().orElse(0))
       .build());
```

Comment: What is your function named `map` expected to do? Considering it returns an Optional that's very strange for a `map` operation (whose name comes from functional programming) In addition, what's the return type of .build()?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach He is using an Optional object, and calling the `map()` on that.

Comment: But then, Ryan is right: I think you should show us the signature of **build()**. And for a mcve, you probably only need builder.build() ... how you setup your object there doesnt matter to the problem here. The only thing that matters is what exactly build is returning. Well, to be precise: the signature of the method that has this return statement `return locationAPIResponse.map()` matters, too. The point is the the compiler fails to "connect" your usage of `map()` to the signature of the method where you use your return!

Answer (score 6):

This simply the syntax for a method-local generic type.

By declaring it directly in the method signature, that U is bound to the context of this method.

You use that in situations where the generic parameter can or should **not** be known on class level (for example when you have a static method that needs generic parameters).

For the compiler error, we need more information. The only thing we can say so far: the signature of the method that uses the given return statement `return locationAPIResponse.map() ...` doesn't match what your mapper is returning!

Comment: Hey, thanks! I more of less understand what you're saying, although we are definitely at the edge of my Java abilities. Can you explain why the compilation is failing? As best as I can tell, LocationContext is of type U. I looked at the map implementation and it ultimately wraps the return value in an Optional, so I don't get what more it wants from me

Comment: For that, we might need a bit more context ([mcve]), mainly the client code that tries to use that method. It also looks like you call map() as a static method on a class, but it isn't declared to be static? So, for the compiler error, we can't help unless you enable us to...

Comment: No, sorry it's very misleading. I'm very sloppy about following camelcase, and LocationAPIResponse is actually a local variable of type Optional. I will try to edit and create a more robust, minimal, complete and verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

The first U is the required syntax for a generic method and the second U in the Optional is a generic class and the return type that will take the generic type U in this methods context as parameter.
Please refer the docs for more
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html